# extending create-react-app getting Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, create-react-app

I'm trying to extend the create-react-app with new folders and files outside of the /src directory. But this is by default not allowed by create-react-app. I tried to import a .json with this command:
`const contractABI = require('../../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json')`
The error message:

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

I tried to create a symbolic link like so: `mklink /d \MyContracts \artifacts\contracts\MyNFT.sol`
This was successful `\MyContracts <<===>> \artifacts\contracts\MyNFT.sol`

Now, how can I import it into my react javascript file? I tried `const contractABI = require('MyContracts/MyNFT.json')` without success.

Any help would be great or any other approach how to solve this issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by adding `paths: {artifacts: "./src/artifacts"}` to the hardhat.config.js I could configure that hardhat should create the directories and files inside the /src.